# Plotting a function with different parameters sets

Tags: plotting

> Plot $f(r) = - a/r^2-b/r^3$ for the three parameter sets (a=1, b=1), (a=-1, b=-1), (a=0, b=1) in a single plot. The three cases should each be a different color and labeled with its associated parameter set (r ranges from 0 to 10).

I need help with making the plot.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Sumit's solution, but offering a differing labeling scheme based on the fairly new option `PlotLabels`, which I think work better than legends for this plot.

```
f[a_, b_, r_] = -a/r^2 - b/r^3
Plot[{f[1, 1, r], f[-1, -1, r], f[0, 1, r]}, {r, 1, 10}, 
  PlotLabels -> {"(a=1, b=1)", "(a=-1, b=-1)", "(a=0, b=1)"}]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update

I got to thinking that it would be nice to have an implementation that would work for a general list of parameter pairs. This is what I came up with.

```
With[{params = {{-1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}},
  Module[{avals, bvals, curves, lbls, items},
    {avals, bvals} = Transpose @ params; 
    curves = MapThread[-#1/r^2 - #2/r^3 &, {avals, bvals}]; 
    lbls = MapThread[Row[{" a=", #1, ", b=", #2}] &, {avals, bvals}];
    items =
      MapThread[
        Callout[#1, #2, {5, (#1 + .03 Sign[#1]) /. r -> 2.7}, {3, #1 /. r -> 3}] &, 
        {curves, lbls}];
    Plot[Evaluate @ items, {r, 1, 10}, ImageSize -> 500]]]
```

[image: fancy_plot]

The callouts must be adjusted by eyeball, but that kind of adjustment must be accepted if one is fussy about label placement.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[a_, b_, r_] = -a/r^2 - b/r^3
Plot[{f[1, 1, r], f[-1, -1, r], f[0, 1, r]}, {r, 1, 10},PlotLegends->{"1,1","-1,1","0,1"}]
```